# Responsive SM and XS alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to develop a code, which has two columns on desktop, when it comes to responsive in 'XS' and 'SM' the first column should be after the second column.

here is the code which i am trying.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="Container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-0">
   First box
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-0">
   Second Box
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

[image: In Desktop it should be viewed like this]

[image: In Responsive it should be viewed like this]

Answer (score 0):

try this. this is in bootstrap. Using the push, pull will help. By the way, i did some cleaning up with your classes too.

```
<section class="Container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                Second Box
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                First box
            </div>          
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The "Second Box" should be push, and the "First Box" should pull. Did you try it on jsfiddle or bootply?

Comment: nope. thank you. It seems like you're tailing my answers. Thanks by the way. :D

Answer (score 0):

You just need to think "mobile first" and put the "2" column first in your markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      Second Box
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      First box
    </div>          
  </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/mexjTUoy6m

Also the `Container-fluid` is doing nothing since CSS is case sensitive so you'll want to be careful with class names.